# List comprehension instead of nested for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nested

I have this which works, but I would like to put this into a list comprehension to save computing power

```
emp_id=df_hours["EMPLOYEE"]
emp_list=df_item["EMPLOYEE"]

##############
#loop through and get values for the day for hours worked per server, and add them to building df
#############

hours_worked=df_hours["HOURS"]
emp_found=[]
 
for x in range(len(emp_list)):
    for i in range(len(emp_id)):
        if emp_list[x] == emp_id[i]:
            emp_found.append(hours_worked[i])

inex=0
last=len(emp_list)
hours_wored=emp_found[inex:last]
df_item['HRS']=hour_worked
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for

```
emp_found = [hours_worked[i] for i in range(len(emp_id)) for x in range(len(emp_list)) if emp_list[x] == emp_id[i]]
```

Comment: will try it, thanks

Comment: yes this does work.  Does this use less resources or does it compute in the same amount of time and use less computing power?

Comment: Glad it worked! Both ways of coding this require the same amount of calculations so I think there will be no difference. I actually think the way you have it is more readable haha

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter, more elegant way:

```
print(list(set(df_hours["EMPLOYEE"]).intersection(set(df_item["EMPLOYEE"]))))
```

Since what you are looking for is getting a list with all common values, you can transform each column to a set, and get the intersection. Then you can convert back the result to a list.

I find this syntax shorter and you might say; more pythonic.

Comment: thank you, haven't tried it yet - but still - thank you

Comment: this doesn't error, but it doesn't join the intersection, and I'm left with an empty list